# how to get resolutions with file extention in pytube

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

```
from pytube import YouTube

link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXb3EKWsInQ"
yt = YouTube(link)
resolutions = []
video_resolutions = []
video_res = []
for stream in yt.streams.filter(subtype="mp4").order_by("resolution"):
    video_resolutions.append(stream.resolution)
print(video_resolutions)
```

result
['144p', '144p', '144p', '240p', '240p', '240p', '360p', '360p', '360p', '360p', '480p', '480p', '480p', '720p', '720p', '720p', '720p', '1080p', '1080p', '1080p', '1440p', '1440p', '2160p', '2160p']

i am trying to build a yt video Downloader but i am stuck at getting resolution , because the streams list is repetitive

Comment: Theres more to the video than the resolution, each `stream` object has different `vcodec` and possible `fps` (30 or 60). Theres an `.itag` (YouTube format identifier code) on each object that people often use to differentiate between which youtube stream they want.  You'll have to pick which one you want to use, there is no obvious 'best' itag to download at -- different videos will look better in different `vcodec`s

Comment: so what should i do to show the available resolution of the video to download

Comment: if you just don't care about duplicates, convert your`video_resolutions` to a set, like `video_res = set()` and then add like `video_resolutions.add(stream.resolution)`